# How Equation label in \begin{cases}

Tags: equations

I would like to present the below equation using equation numbers. But it does not show it in the pdf file. Has anybody an idea? Thanks

```
\[ \varphi(x,y) =
\begin{cases} \label{ch:five:sec:5:eq4:1}
      1 & if \quad |I(x,y) - \overline{I(x,y)}|> JND_{ST}(x,y), \\
      0 & \quad \quad \quad otherwise \\
   \end{cases}
\]
```

Comment: Look at the cases package

Comment: Do you need to number each case or do you want just a global number?

Comment: @Cagri Then use `\begin{equation}` instead of `\[` and `\end{equation}` instead of `\]`; move the `\label` just after `\begin{equation}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not `\label` that generates the equation number: use the `equation` environment instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{ch:five:sec:5:eq4:1}
\varphi(x,y) =
\begin{cases} 
      1 & \text{if $|I(x,y) - \overline{I(x,y)}|> \mathit{JND}_{\mathrm{ST}}(x,y)$}, \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]