# How to use Latex to create 3 sets of equations with brackets

Tags: math-mode

Could anyone can help me how to type the following equations in latex?

[image: equation]

Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please help us to help you by providing what you have manage to do till now in a compilable minimal working example. (See here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/120578) Edit: Related question is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229464/how-equation-label-in-begincases

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm,eqparbox}
\newcommand{\tsum}{\textstyle\sum}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      \epsilon\, \dot{z}^i  &= \eqmakebox[RHS][l]{$-(z^i + u^i) - \sum_{i = j}^N \bm{L}_{ij} (z^j + \nu^j)$,} \\
      \eqmakebox[LHS][r]{$\epsilon\, \dot{\nu}^i$} &= \tsum_{j = 1}^N \bm{L}_{ji} z^j,
    \end{aligned}
  \right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace \\
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      \epsilon\, \dot{y}^i  &= \eqmakebox[RHS][l]{$-(y^i + \dot{u}^i) - \sum_{i = j}^N \bm{L}_{ij} (y^j + \mu^j)$,} \\
      \eqmakebox[LHS][r]{$\epsilon\, \dot{\mu}^i$} &= \tsum_{j = 1}^N \bm{L}_{ji} y^j,
    \end{aligned}
  \right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace \\
  \eqmakebox[LHS][r]{$\dot{x}^i$} = \eqmakebox[RHS][l]{$-\beta^i x^i - \beta^i z^i - y^i$.}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) ensures that we can place content in boxes that will be the same width. This helps with alignment across the structures (`aligned`) within `align`. Minor removal of `\kern`ing as a result of a blank `\right.` delimiter aligns the equations as needed.

One could also have used a `cases` environment to achieve the braces sub-equations.